# Listview contains a checkbox and multiple text views and the check boxes generate dynamically but gives a null pointer exception

Tags: android

My `ListView` contains a `CheckBox` and multiple `TextViews` and the checkBoxes generate dynamically on a specific click, but when i run the code to generate these check boxes it runs fine for the first 10 list view rows after that it gives a `NULLPointerException`.

How can i correct it

Following is the snippet of my code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
int size = listView.getAdapter().getCount();

for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
    chk.setVisibility(1);
}

Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
btnDone.setVisibility(1);
```

Comment: [Off-topic] I'd suggest that you don't use `.setVisibility(1)`.

Comment: Have you tried to use an Adapter and create these checkoxes in the `getView()` method of the adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Because only 10 items are visible on the list now, listView.getAdapter().getCount() gets the count of items on the total list, not just visible.

You're probably getting the null pointer on listView.getChildAt(i).

ListViews only have the items that are visible right now, for example, if you can display 10 items and you scrolled to item 10, it displays items from index 10 to 19, so in this case listView.getChildAt(0) will get you the 10 item and not the 0.

I'd suggest you change the display or not of the checkbox on the getView() method and if runtime changes you change only the visible ones.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what is happening
I didn't get how to use getView() .... Please explain 

Thanx

Comment: On the getView() method you set the visibility of the checkbox. If the visibility changes by the user action, maybe you should have a list of items visible, so when android calls getView() with position 10, you check if on position 10 the checkbox is visible or not and sets the visibility for it.